# Euclidean vs. cosine similarity

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, clustering, text-mining, bigdata

I have a text dataset which I vectorize using a tfidf technique and now in order to make a cluster analysis I am measuring distances between these vector representations. I have found that a common technique is to measure distance using cosine similarity, and when I ask why euclidean distance is not used, the common answer is that cosine similarity works better when vectors have different magnitude.

Since my text vectorized representation is **normalized** I wonder which is the advantage of using cosine similarity over euclidean distance in order to cluster my data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On L2 normalized data it is an easy and good exercise to prove that they are equivalent.

So you should try to solve the math yourself.

Hint: use squared Euclidean.

Note that it is common with tfidf to *not* have normalized data because of various technical reasons, e.g., when using inverted indexes in text search. Furthermore, cosine is faster on very sparse data.

Comment: That's very useful. I will prove the equivalence.

Comment: @FedericoCaccia You could write the prove as an answer here.

Comment: The proof is so straightforward that you are better served doing it yourself than just reading it here. That is why I didn't include it.